# In Banach algebra $A$ if $a^2=a$ show that $\sigma_A(a)\subseteq\{0,1\}$

Tags: spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra with identity $e$ and let $x\in A  $ be such that $a^2=a$ show that $\sigma_A(a)\subseteq\{0,1\}$ and compute the resolvet function $$R(a, \lambda)=(\lambda e-a)^{-1}$$

Any ideas or insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lambda \neq 0,1$ then $\frac 1 {\lambda} (e+\frac a {\lambda -1})$ is the inverse of $\lambda e-a$. [To arrive at this you can  pretend that the Banach algebra is the real line and write $\frac 1 {a-\lambda}=\frac 1 {\lambda} (a/\lambda -1)^{-1}$ and use the expansion $\frac 1 {1-x} =\sum x^{n}$. Of cousre this proves nothing  but it helps us you to guess what the inverse of $ae-\lambda$ is likely to be].

Comment: @ Dear Kavi Rama Murthy it is so useful many thanks

Comment: I'd like to khow is it make sense? by $a^2=a$  we have $a=0$ or $a=e$

so $0e-a$ and $1e-a$ are not invertible

Comment: No, this is not correct. Cancellation law does not hold in a Banach algebra and $a^{2}=a$ does not imply $a=0$ or $a=e$. I fact cancellation is possible only when the Banach algebra is one dimensional.

Comment: I'd like to know where we have to use the condition $a^2=a$?

Comment: Verification of the fact that the element I have given is the inverse of $\lambda e-a$  using $a^{2}=a$ is straightforward. If you are asking where I used $a^{2}=a$ in the heuristic argument you have to look at the series $\sum (a/ \lambda )^{n}$. Replace $a^{n}$ by $a$ for all $n \geq 1$ to compute this sum.

Comment: @user62498 You are not asked to prove that $0e-a$ and $1e-a$ are not invertible. In fact this may be false. If $a=e$ then $0e-a$ is invertible. You only have to prove that the spectrum is contained in $\{0,1\}$, not equal to it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to solve $(\lambda e-a)^{-1}=re+sa$.
We get
$$e=(\lambda e-a)(re+sa)=\lambda re+(\lambda s-r-s)a.$$
So we need $\lambda r=1$. So we get $r$ when $\lambda\ne0$. Also
we need $0=-r+(\lambda-1)s$ and we get $s$ when $\lambda\ne1$.

Comment: thanks, by $a^2=a$  we have $a=0$ or $a=e$

so $0e-a$ and $1e-a$ are not invertible is it make sense?